# Day rate discount

Tags: php, discount

I am creating an intranet for a vehicle hire company

I set the default price as such:

```
$dayRate = '90.00';
```

I have created a field on my table to store a discount day rate if needed, called `disc_day_rate` which defaults to 0.

I pull the discount price as such

```
$discDayRate = $hire['disc_day_rate'];
```

I wish to find the lowest of these two numbers, but I think the default `disc_day_rate` of 0 is causing issues

I have tried using `min();` and `if ($discDayrate == "0")` methods but after finding many answers on stackoverflow without having to post my own It's time to ask for help with an elegant solution

Comment: What happens if you set your default discount day rate to $1,000,000 instead of $0?

Comment: You'll get higher quality responses if you include the platform as a tag, rather than a feature name.  This looks a little like PHP...

Comment: SELF DIAGNOSED: min(array_filter(array($dayRate,$discDayRate)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ensures the `0.00` will never cause you a problem.

```
if ($discDayRate == 0.00) { ## don't use quotes here; it should be saved as a DECIMAL or INT in the database
   $the_rate = $dayRate; ## back to the default
}
else {
   if ($discDayRate < $dayRate) {
      $the_rate = $diskDayRate;
   }
   else {
      $the_rate = $dayRate;
   }
}
```

`$the_rate` has your desired rate.

Comment: Thanks David. That would have fixed my original method but since posting I have alose solved this by using `array_filter` in min(), line this: `min(array_filter(array($dayRate,$discDayRate)))`